# cannot define a correlation name more than once

Tags: search, stock, out-of-stock

we are using this extension : `https://github.com/r-martins/Magento-OutOfStockLast` for following purpose.

if we click on any category link, initially we are displaying in-stock-products and than we are displaying out-of-stock products as below.

ex : http://sitename.com/testing.html

like same way, when we search in search bar, we want to display In-stock-products first and than out-of-stock products

we are using this extension for this: `https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/sphinx-search-ultimate.html` its working fine.

once we use both extension, than we are getting this error when we search something :

http://sitename.com/catalogsearch/result/\?q=funskool

**You cannot define a correlation name '_inventory_table' more than once**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It remembers a very common error that happens when you include a layer block more than once. But in this case is an extension compatibility problem.

I'm afraid that your error is pretty similar, but in that case you are dealing with 3rd party extensions. So try to find the code where they are changing or filtering collection and then removes the join statement of one of them.

One more thing: Try to debug collection before and after both modules filters you can use:

```
Mage::log(__METHOD__);
Mage::log($collection->getSelectSql(true));
... extension 1 filter stuff ...
Mage::log($collection->getSelectSql(true));

...
Mage::log(__METHOD__);
Mage::log($collection->getSelectSql(true));
... extension 2 filter stuff...
Mage::log($collection->getSelectSql(true));
```

Sorry i couldn't be more specific just because i don't have these extensions.

Comment: can you help me in finding out file path, usually in which file i need to modify ? is it happens if both modules rewrites an specific class ?

Comment: look at both config.xml files and search for: blocks rewrites model rewrites and global/frontend observers it would give you an idea about where the black magic is applied :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer update, i just added a method name log

Comment: i will check it...